# SQL - Combining 2 Extracting Functions for 1 field

Tags: sql, substring, charindex

I have a String containing user profiles where the first part of the data is always the same and the second data is always variable.
I need to extract the midle part

**Example of String ;**

```
ABC_01_Operator ,XX=ALPHABET-XYZ
ABC_07_Admin ,XX=ALPHABET-XYZ
```

**Data I want to Extract:**

```
01_Operator
07_Admin
```

I have 2 Functions that extract a part but I can't find a way to combine them

```
1) SUBSTRING (MyField, 5, 12) to start from 01 / 07
2) LEFT(MyField, CHARINDEX(',XX', MyField) - 1)
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: `SUBSTRING(LEFT(MyField, CHARINDEX(',XX', MyField) - 1),5,100)`

Comment: Try my answer, hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `(2)` as first parameter of `(1)` like this (set a reasonably high value for substring length):

```
select SUBSTRING(LEFT(@MyField, CHARINDEX(',XX', @MyField) - 1),5, 1000);
```

Comment: Perfect! It's Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Answer:

```
DECLARE @MyField VARCHAR(100)='ABC_01_Operator ,XX=ALPHABET-XYZ'

SELECT RIGHT(LEFT(@MyField, CHARINDEX(',XX', @MyField) - 1)
    ,LEN(LEFT(@MyField, CHARINDEX(',XX', @MyField) - 1))-3)
```

**Result:**

```
01_Operator 
07_Admin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both functions simultaneously to generate your result as

```
SELECT substring(MyField, 5, charindex('XX', MyField, 1)-2)
```

Comment: This only takes care of one function